# How do I rearrange sections in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created 5 sections in crystal report and I want section 3 to be on top of section 2. I tried dragging the sections but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer under Section Expert. Highlight the section you want to rearrange the click the arrow beside the Merge Button. Changes will appear after clicking OK.